# Insert Space in between a CamelCase String

Tags: html, asp.net, regex, asp.net-mvc

I have a insert space in between string(camelcase) in the view page.
In view

```
<span>@Model.Data</span>
```

The `Model.Date` has a value equal to `UploadDataToServer`
My expected o/p is `Upload Data To Server`
Thanks in advance

Comment: Replace `([A-Z])` by ` $1` and then `trim`.

Comment: need a working example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using:

```
([A-Z])
```

And replacing with `$1` (note the space before `$`) does the job. See [Live Demo](https://regex101.com/r/cD8fI5/1)

Answer (score 1):

Another approach would be to use [a positive lookbehind/-ahead](https://regex101.com/r/oZ4zI4/1):

```
(?<=[a-z])(?=[A-Z])
```